# How to create a layout like Stream in Google+ Android App

Tags: android, layout, tabs, slide

I would like to create an activity with layout like has Google+ Android App for example in Stream section (See image below - I couldn't post an image, so only link).

To be specific, I mean ActionBar and **tab slider under it**, which can **change tabs by finger sliding**. It should be working also on devices running Gingerbread (2.3) at least.
Is somewhere a tutorial how to create these sliding tabs?
Thank you

Sample what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpDnM.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to is a ViewPager. Take a look at this blogpost from a Googler: http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html

You could also have a look at the IOSched example from this year's Google IO:
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout